# Sampling inhomogeneous spatial point processes

Tags: graphs-and-networks, probability-or-statistics

I am looking to generate a [point process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process) (random set of points) in a disk of radius $R$, but where the intensity measure decays, for $r$ the distance from the origin of the disk, as $\exp(-r^2/2)$. Is there a standard way to do this in Mathematica?

In the simpler case where the intensity measure is uniform I can sample by using a set of random reals, where the number of points is Poisson. To model the non-uniform intensity, I could just discretise the space, and pick a random number of points in each cell which is decaying as appropriate, but is there a more `built in' way?

Comment: Isn't this just sampling from a truncated 2D normal distribution? For `n` points, radius `R`, `Select[
 RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, 2}],
 Norm[#] <= R &
 ]`

Comment: And you can just pick $n$ as a Poisson?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Of course, sampling the x and y coordinates independently works only for the normal distribution. This simplified method won't work for most other distributions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using the new spatial statistics from v12.2:

```
{x0, y0} = {1.5, 2};
σ = .7;
R = 3.0;
reg = Disk[{x0, y0}, R];
pts = RandomPointConfiguration[
   InhomogeneousPoissonPointProcess[
    Function[10000*Exp[-((#1 - x0)^2 + (#2 - y0)^2)/(2*σ)]], 
    2], reg];
Show[RegionPlot[reg], ListPlot[pts]]
```

[image: point process]

Comment: Ok I will download 12.2!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a pedestrian way to achieve the same that also works with older MMA:

We first define the normalized ProbabilityDistribution of the radius:`p`

```
r0 = 1;
pdf[x_] = Exp[-x^2/2]/Integrate[  Exp[-y^2/2], {y, 0, r0}]
p = ProbabilityDistribution[pdf[x], {x, 0, r0}];
```

With this distribution we can create r-values: `r`. The angle is uniformly distributed, what we can achieve simply by `RandomReal`. From `r` and `phi` we can get x/y coordinates and draw the points:

```
n = 10^4;
pts = MapThread[#1 {Cos[#2], Sin[#2]} &, {RandomVariate[p, n], 
    RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, n]}];
Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, r0], PointSize[0.001], Point[pts]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that works well, particularly if you just want the points. Only thing is p=ProbabilityDistribution should be should be p1=ProbabilityDistribution.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected this.